# Cakephp _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'method_cache'

Tags: php, cakephp, caching, logging

Warning: Warning (512): _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'method_cache' to Apc cache in [/var/www/****/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 323]

```
Trace:
Cache::write() - CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 323
DboSource::__destruct() - CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php, line 3541
[main] - [internal], line ??
```

Writes on /app/tmp folder:

```
drwxrwsr-x  7 apache apache 4096 Sep 27  2014 tmp
```

sub-folders:

```
drwxrwsr-x 5 apache apache 4096 Jun  2 16:51 cache
drwxrwsr-x 3 apache apache 4096 Jul 21 13:40 logs
drwxrwsr-x 3 apache apache 4096 Jun 27  2014 sessions
drwxrwsr-x 3 apache apache 4096 Jun 27  2014 tests
```

Does anyone has any idea about this warning and how to remove this?

Answer (score 0):

You should make your sub directories also writable

- app/tmp/cache
- app/tmp/cache/persistent
- app/tmp/cache/models